# Sprite not rotating around its centre after Scaling at its centre

Tags: android, geometry, andengine

If I scale a sprite at its centre , and then try to rotate it around its centre as well, 
rotation doesnot occur around its centre.

If you need to rotate, for example a scaled ball, the way  its working it  is set the  scale center at  the    **top,left (0,0)** set the scale that you want, and then set the rotation center to the middle of the scaled sprite, and then apply the rotation modifier.

```
blaBloBliSprite.setScaleCenter(0, 0);
blaBloBliSprite.setScale(0.667f);
blaBloBliSprite.setPosition(557, CAMERA_HEIGHT / 2 - blaBloBliSprite.getHeightScaled() / 2);
blaBloBliSprite.setRotationCenter(blaBloBliSprite.getWidthScaled() / 2,
blaBloBliSprite.getHeightScaled() / 2);
```

BUT I WANT TO SCALE A SPRITE AT ITS CENTER AS WELL.

How to achieve this ?
Will the anchor branch of ANDengine resolve it??

Comment: What version are you using? GLES2 and GLES2-AnchorCenter have different coordinate systems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the trick is that setScaleCenter is not working the way you expect. If you set it to 0,0 it will scale at the top left, even in anchor center.

try using 1/2 the width and height of the sprite:

```
blaBloBliSprite.setScaleCenter(blaBloBliSprite.getWidth()/2, blaBloBliSprite.getHeight()/2 );
```

As an aside, switching to anchor center will fix your base problem as the default position for the scale and rotation center is the center of a Sprite. But even in anchor center 0,0 is the top left for the scale and rotation center. Its just positioned to the middle by default.